# Mejorar contador registros por mes del año

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

Actualizo pregunta, a ver si puede pasar los datos del array al script de charts.js con comas "," para que pueda sacar los graficos. En este caso el array viene a recopilar el numero de registros por mes del año, a partir de aqui me genera un numero al querer pasarlo al JS del charts.js que solo recoge todos los numeros pero sin coma, he probado con el JSON.parse pero pasa el valor 0.

```
<?php
$contador_de_accidentes_mes = array('01' => 0, '02' => 0, '03' => 0, '04' => 0,'05' => 0, '06' => 0, '07' => 0, '08' => 0,'09' => 0, '10' => 0, '11' => 0, '12' => 0);

  foreach ($accidentes_datos as $accidentes_dato) {
    $mesaccidente = date("m", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));
    $anioaccidente = date("Y", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));

    if ($anioaccidente == $anio && isset($contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente])) {
      $contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente]++;
    }
  }

  foreach ($contador_de_accidentes_mes as $mes => $contador) {
    echo "$contador";
  
  }
  ?>

<script>
  var contador_de_accidentes_mes = JSON.parse(<?php echo my_json_string?>);
</script>
 Aqui es el fragmento JS de la grafica 

<script>
var chartDom = document.getElementById('graficaaccidentes');
  var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
  var option;

  option = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      axisPointer: {
        type: 'shadow'
      }
    },
    grid: {
      left: '3%',
      right: '4%',
      bottom: '3%',
      containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'category',
      data: ['En', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
      axisTick: {
        alignWithLabel: true
      }
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value'
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: '60%',
      data: [<?php echo $my_json_string?>],
    }]
  };
  option && myChart.setOption(option);
</script>´´´
```

Comment: Hola Emili, podrías empezar por calcular una sola vez el año y mes de `fecha_fr` y guardarlos en variables. También podrías preguntar una sola vez si el año es igual a `$anio` y finalmente podrías crear un arreglo asociativo para sumar dependiendo del número del mes, la cantidad es constante, dudo mucho que en el corto plazo dejen de ser 12 meses.

Comment: Es mas todo eso lo puede calcular la DB al hacer la query. En este caso, esto no tiene mucho sentido. y en general, si son contadores, ya deberian estar precalculados...

Comment: por lo que comentas marcos, si que lo podria simplificar en:   ``` foreach ($formaciones_datos as $formaciones_dato) {
  $mesformacion = date("m", strtotime($formaciones_dato['fecha_fr']));
  $anioformacion = date("Y", strtotime($formaciones_dato['fecha_fr']));
if($anioformacion == $anio){
    elseif ($mesformacion == 1 ) {
      $contador_de_formaciones_en = $contador_de_formaciones_en + 1;
    } elseif ($mesformacion == 2 ) {
      $contador_de_formaciones_fe = $contador_de_formaciones_fe + 1;}}
    ?>```

Comment: @EmiliVives, exacto, ahí va. Ahora, pensa que si el año es el correcto, podes incrementar el valor en un arreglo basandote en el número del mes, no te hacen falta esos `if($mesformacion == x)`. PD: Estoy tentado a responder, pero estoy seguro de que vas a poder resolverlo por tu cuenta.

Comment: no suelo responder este tipo de preguntas por que suelen estar basadas en opiniones, pero considero que cuando se intenta refactorizar obligatoriamente tienes que pensar fuera de la caja (lo que conoces) y evaluar diferentes opciones (no opiniones) entonces poder determinar cual opcion se adecua mejor a tu escenario... estare conversando con algunos compañeros del sitio antes de darte una respuesta...

Comment: Podrías usar un arreglo de 12 elementos para los contadores, en lugar de 12 variables separadas, 12 if separados, etc. ¿PHP tiene arreglos?

Comment: Gracias Marcos, ha sido muy alentadora tu aportacion

Comment: Gracias Francisco, como supongo habras observado soy novato (-1 año) en este tema, intento aprender de cada obstaculo que encuentro y aportacion vuestra, si que es verdad que la opcion no es igual a la opinion aunque el post va ligado a mi opinion ya que no conozco todas las opciones.

Comment: en el primer mes de php deberias aprender sobre tipos de variables, y estructuras de codigo (condicionales, bucles), el segundo o tercer mes deberias estar biendo tipos de datos y funciones nativas... como para manejo de fechas etc ...

Answer (score 2):

AS-IS: No tiene el filtrado por año que mencionas, ese te lo dejo que lo implementes. Pero si te dejo una forma diferente de plantearlo.

Cuando queremos optimizar un código, porque creemos que lo que esta no es adecuado o no es correcto en cuanto a planteamiento y funcionalidad y escalabilidad, debemos recurrir a metodología de la investigación basada en la experiencia y en las mejores prácticas... en principio lo que buscas es eso re factorizar tu código a una versión más legible, mantenerle y escalable...

Te daré una respuesta basada en las opciones que yo consideraría, que serían la mejor práctica manteniendo el nivel y esquema de lo que has presentado.

Una forma de hacerlo es utilizando matrices asociativas para almacenar los contadores por mes, este es un ejemplo practico:

```
<?php

# partiendo de este arreglo de ejemplo:
$formaciones_datos = array(
    array('fecha_fr' => '2023-01-15', 'otro_dato' => 'valor'),
    array('fecha_fr' => '2023-02-20', 'otro_dato' => 'valor'),
    array('fecha_fr' => '2023-03-10', 'otro_dato' => 'valor'),
    // Otros datos de formaciones con fechas diferentes
);


# Inicializar el array de contadores por mes
$contador_de_formaciones_por_mes = array(
    '01' => 0, // Enero
    '02' => 0, // Febrero
    '03' => 0, // Marzo
    '04' => 0, // Abril
    '05' => 0, // Mayo
    '06' => 0, // Junio
    '07' => 0, // Julio
    '08' => 0, // Agosto
    '09' => 0, // Septiembre
    '10' => 0, // Octubre
    '11' => 0, // Noviembre
    '12' => 0  // Diciembre
);

# Iterar sobre los datos y contar por mes
foreach ($formaciones_datos as $formaciones_dato) {
    $mes = date("m", strtotime($formaciones_dato['fecha_fr']));
    $contador_de_formaciones_por_mes[$mes]++;
}
?>
```

Y en la salida:

```
<!-- Mostrar los resultados -->
<?php foreach ($contador_de_formaciones_por_mes as $mes => $contador): ?>
    <p>Formaciones en <?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $mes)->format('F'); ?>: <?php echo $contador; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Ahora, respecto a la optimización:***

- Se reemplaza un conjunto de múltiples variables contadoras y condicionales largas con un solo array asociativo.
- Esto hace que el código sea más limpio, más fácil de leer y mantener.
  Además, reduce la duplicación de código y simplifica la lógica, ya que no es necesario repetir las mismas condiciones para cada mes individualmente.
- La utilización de funciones integradas de PHP, como date(), strtotime() y DateTime::createFromFormat(), ayuda a simplificar el manejo de fechas y tiempos.

**Nota:** es posible que otros usuarios tengan otras opciones a implementar, todo dependera si estan trabajando con algun estandar especifico o framework lo que seria bueno conocer tambien.

Te recomiendo visitar y estudiar el sitio en ingles: [PHP The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com/) es el mejor punto de partida y en donde encontraras documentado los principales y diferentes caminos que tiene PHP

Comment: Te estaría faltando agregar la condición de que el año del `$formaciones_dato` coincida con el año que se obtiene de la variable `$fechahoraentera`.

Comment: osea por año, esa parte me la salte jajajajajajaaja ... es que no se le puede dar todo XD...

Comment: @Marcos crees que seria bueno terminarle la tarea o se la dejamos hasta aqui.. creo que lo mas dificil, adaptar los if y conbinarlos con ciclos ... era el objetivo principal ...

Comment: Era solamente una observación. Te darás cuenta que no respondí, justamente para darle la oportunidad de resolverlo por si mismo. Si nos queremos poner en finos... tu respuesta NO devolvería el resultado esperado.

Comment: el no esta preguntando por devolver un resultado esperado ... la pregunta de el es: ***pero no se si realmente deberia ser asi o bien plantearlo de otra manera***

Comment: No estoy diciendo que tu respuesta este mal. El código que tiene funciona y busca mejorarlo. El código que le ofreces hace lo segundo y no lo primero. Si consideras que tu respuesta esta completa, dejala así.

Comment: bueno yo respondi a lo que el pregunto xD

Comment: @Marcos yo he participado en codereview... y las respuesta de refactorizacion incluyen codigos de ejemplos de posibles implementaciones para explicar el codigo y no necesariamente un codigo explicito ... ya que el refactorizar busca implementar y aprender nuevas y otras formas de hacer las cosas ganandole terreno a los distintos niveles de programacion.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151768/discussion-between-marcos-and-francisco-nunez-ia-lover).

Comment: Hola Marcos y Francisco, al final me va genial la propuesta de marcos y la he implementado en otras partes.

Comment: Tengo una duda a ver si soys podeis ayudarme: obtenidos los datos con el foreach, quiero pasarlos a JS para que en un grafico los recoge, creo que no coge la "," y los pone todos juntos y al final genera un valor de 200010000 en lugar de 2, 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0.   En este caso lo paso tal cual el foreach en el script:  data: [<?php foreach ($contador_de_accidentes_mes as $mes => $contador) {
                echo "$contador";
              }
              ?>]
    }]

Comment: crea un array y cada vez que pases un ciclo puedes hacer algo como: $array[]=$dato; cuando termines el ciclo foreach convierte el array en un JsonString y lo puedes devolver con un echo para que el js lo recoja como indicas: 2,0,0,0,1,0,0

Comment: Hola @FranciscoNuñezIALover lo he intentado implementar como me comentas  pero no termino de entenderlo. TE paso codigo a ver si ves como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: $contador_de_accidentes_mes = array(
    '01' => 0, '02' =>...
  );
  foreach ($accidentes_datos as $accidentes_dato) {
    $mesaccidente = date("m", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));
    $anioaccidente = date("Y", strtotime($accidentes_dato['fecha_ace']));

    if ($anioaccidente == $anio && isset($contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente])) {
      $contador_de_accidentes_mes[$mesaccidente]++;
    }
  }

  $my_json_string = json_encode($contador_de_accidentes_mes);
  }
  ?>

Comment: ----   y despues en el Script del grafico donde introduzco los valores ----           data: [JSON.parse(<?php echo $my_json_string?>)]

Comment: actualiza tu pregunta con lo que has hecho